# SUM values in SQL starting from a specific point in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sum, subquery

I have a table that lists the index/order, the name, and the value. For example, it looks like this:

```
TABLE1:
ID | NAME | VALUE
1  | A    | 2
2  | B    | 5
3  | C    | 2
4  | D    | 7
5  | E    | 0
```

Now, I have another table that has a random list of NAMEs. It'll just show either A, B, C, D, or E. Depending on what the NAME is, I wanted to calculate the SUM of all the values that it will take to get to E. Does that make sense?

So if for example, my table looks like this:

```
TABLE2:
NAME
D
B
A
```

I'd want another column next to NAME that'll show the sum. So D would have 7 because the next event is E. B would have to be the sum of 5, 2, and 7 because B is 5, and C is 2, and D is 7. And A would have the sum of 2, 5, 3, and 7 and so on.

Hopefully this is easy to understand.

I actually don't have much at all aside from joining the two tables and getting the current value of the NAME. But I wasn't sure how to increment and so on and keep adding?

```
SELECT T2.NAME, T1.VALUE
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME
```

Is doing this even possible? Or am I wasting my time? Should I be referring to actual code to do this? Or should I make a function?

I wasn't sure where to start and I was hoping someone could help me out.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a running sum; this is a normal windowing function: see this: https://www.wagonhq.com/blog/running-totals-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As gregory suggests, you can do this with a simple windowed function, which (in this case) will sum up all the rows after and including the current one based on the `ID` value.  Obviously there are a number of different ways in which you can slice your data, though I'll leave that up to you to explore :)

---

```
declare @t table(ID int,Name nvarchar(50),Val int);
insert into @t values(1,'A',2),(2,'B',5),(3,'C',2),(4,'D',7),(5,'E',0);

select ID      -- The desc makes the preceding work the right way. This is 
        ,Name  -- essentially shorthand for "sum(Val) over (order by ID rows between current row and unbounded following)"
        ,Val   -- which is functionally the same, but a lot more typing...
        ,sum(Val) over (order by ID desc rows unbounded preceding) as s 
from @t
order by ID;
```

Which will output:

```
+----+------+-----+----+
| ID | Name | Val | s  |
+----+------+-----+----+
|  1 | A    |   2 | 16 |
|  2 | B    |   5 | 14 |
|  3 | C    |   2 |  9 |
|  4 | D    |   7 |  7 |
|  5 | E    |   0 |  0 |
+----+------+-----+----+
```

Comment: Wow, this one worked very nicely and only required one extra line. I will definitely have to look into this windowed function more thoroughly but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @chakolatemilk  There are several different ways you can use the `over` cluase, particularly with `partition` which groups up your data to provide the aggregations.  They are fantastic additions to SQL that save a huge amount of data wrangling.

Answer (score 2):

The query is in two parts; this is hard to see at first, so I'll walk through each step.

**Step 1: Obtain the rolling sum**

Join table1 to itself for any letters greater than itself:

```
select *
    from table1 t1
    inner join table1 t2 on t2.name >= t1.name
    order by t1.name
```

This produces the following table

```
+ -- + ---- + ----- + -- + ---- + ----- +
| id | name | value | id | name | value |
+ -- + ---- + ----- + -- + ---- + ----- +
| 1  | A    | 2     | 1  | A    | 2     |
| 1  | A    | 2     | 2  | B    | 5     |
| 1  | A    | 2     | 3  | C    | 2     |
| 1  | A    | 2     | 4  | D    | 7     |
| 1  | A    | 2     | 5  | E    | 0     |
| 2  | B    | 5     | 2  | B    | 5     |
| 2  | B    | 5     | 3  | C    | 2     |
| 2  | B    | 5     | 4  | D    | 7     |
| 2  | B    | 5     | 5  | E    | 0     |
| 3  | C    | 2     | 3  | C    | 2     |
| 3  | C    | 2     | 4  | D    | 7     |
| 3  | C    | 2     | 5  | E    | 0     |
| 4  | D    | 7     | 4  | D    | 7     |
| 4  | D    | 7     | 5  | E    | 0     |
| 5  | E    | 0     | 5  | E    | 0     |
+ -- + ---- + ----- + -- + ---- + ----- +
```

Notice that if we group by the name from t1, we can get the rolling sum by summing the values from t2. This query

```
select  t1.name,
        SUM(t2.value) as SumToE
    from table1 t1
    inner join table1 t2
        on t2.name >= t1.name
    group by t1.name
```

gives us the rolling sums we want

```
+ ---- + ------ +
| name | sumToE |
+ ---- + ------ +
| A    | 16     |
| B    | 14     |
| C    | 9      |
| D    | 7      |
| E    | 0      |
+ ---- + ------ +
```

*Note:* This is equivalent to using a windowed function that sums over a set, but it is much easier to visually see what you're doing via this joining technique.

**Step 2: Join the rolling sum**

Now that you have this rolling sum for each letter, you simply join it to table2 for the letters you want

```
select t1.*
    from table2 t2
    inner join (
        select  t1.name,
                SUM(t2.value) as SumToE
            from table1 t1
            inner join table1 t2
                on t2.name >= t1.name
            group by t1.name
    ) t1 on t1.name = t2.name
```

Result:

```
+ ---- + ------ +
| name | sumToE |
+ ---- + ------ +
| A    | 16     |
| B    | 14     |
| D    | 7      |
+ ---- + ------ +
```

Comment: I'm having a pretty hard time following this.. So for the second query given, is #tab1 the table that was produced in the first query? Because I tried the second query given and it only gave me the same result as Table1 itself. Sorry! Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Sorry about that. I use temp tables when I wrote my code, so that's why the naming is different. My #tab1 is your Table1 and my #tab2 is your Table2. I'll update my answer with those changes

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable2(name VARCHAR(1))
INSERT INTO #tempTable2(name)
VALUES('D')
INSERT INTO #tempTable2(name)
VALUES('B')
INSERT INTO #tempTable2(name)
VALUES('A')


CREATE TABLE #tempTable(id INT, name VARCHAR(1), value INT)
INSERT INTO #temptable(id,name,value)
VALUES(1,'A',2)
INSERT INTO #temptable(id,name,value)
VALUES(2,'B',5)
INSERT INTO #temptable(id,name,value)
VALUES(3,'C',2)
INSERT INTO #temptable(id,name,value)
VALUES(4,'D',7)
INSERT INTO #temptable(id,name,value)
VALUES(5,'E',0)



;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT id, value, name, RunningTotal = value
    FROM dbo.#temptable
    WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM #temptable)

  UNION ALL

    SELECT y.id, y.value, y.name, x.RunningTotal + y.value
    FROM x 
        INNER JOIN dbo.#temptable AS y ON 
            y.id = x.id - 1

)
SELECT x.id, x.value, x.name, x.RunningTotal
  FROM x
    JOIN #tempTable2 t2 ON
        x.name = t2.name
  ORDER BY x.id



DROP TABLE #tempTable
DROP TABLE #tempTable2
```