# SQL sort and last record

Tags: sql

this is my first post so pardon me if my question is not in it's appropriate places or tittle

I have a table like this

```
ID     DATE    Cat  VALUE  
-------------------------    
1   07/07/2018  A   100  
2   07/07/2018  A   200  
3   07/07/2018  B   300  
4   07/07/2018  B   400  
5   07/07/2018  C   500  
6   07/07/2018  C   600  
7   08/07/2018  A   700  
8   08/07/2018  A   800  
9   08/07/2018  B   900  
10  08/07/2018  B   110  
11  08/07/2018  C   120
```

I would like to return

distinct category, sum of value, last record of the category

something like this

```
Cat sumValue    lastrecord
--------------------------
A   1800        800
B   1710        110
C   1220        120
```

is it possible to do it in a single query

thanks

I am able to find the SUM

```
SELECT cat, SUM(value) FROM table GROUP BY cat;
```

and
find the last ID (autonumber key) using MAX

```
SELECT MAX(ID), cat FROM table GROUP BY cat;
```

but i just can't get the value for the last record

Comment: Please give it a try yourself and share your attempts so far with the others.

Comment: Where is sumValue and lastrecord in table ?

Comment: i've tried using select top 1 order by desc but I can't combine it with distinct

Comment: sumValue is Sum of [value] where [cat] = distinct [cat]
lastrecord is the last record by date of particular [cat]

Comment: Try using `SUM`, `GROUP BY` for grouping - you need aggregates. google for aggregates in sql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SUM values in SQL starting from a specific point in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536762/sum-values-in-sql-starting-from-a-specific-point-in-another-table)

Comment: I can find the last date using MAX   
`select cat, sum of value, MAX(date) from table GROUP BY cat;`  
but i just can't get the value for the last record

Comment: You have to use `SUM(Cat)` .... `GROUP BY Cat` to get the group sum

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3577fe/17)

```
SELECT
  t.cat,
  SUM(t.value) as sumValue,
  (
    SELECT
      t3.value
    FROM
      `table` t3
    WHERE
      t3.id = MAX(t2.id)
  ) as lastrecord
FROM
  `table` t
  JOIN
    `table` t2 ON t.id = t2.id
GROUP BY
  cat
```

**EDIT** shorter Version:

```
SELECT
    t.cat,
    SUM(t.value) as sumValue,
    (SELECT value FROM `table` t2 WHERE t2.id = MAX(t.id)) lastValue
FROM
    `table` t
GROUP BY
    t.cat
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
declare @t table (id int, cat char, value int);
insert into @t values 
(1, 'A', 100), 
(2, 'A', 200),   
(3, 'B', 300),   
(4, 'B', 400),   
(5, 'C', 500),   
(6, 'C', 600),   
(7, 'A', 700),   
(8, 'A', 800),   
(9, 'B', 900),   
(10, 'B', 110),   
(11, 'C', 120);  
select cat, value, sum  
from 
( select *
       , sum(value) over (partition by cat) as sum 
       , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by cat order by id desc) as rn 
  from @t
) tt 
where tt.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're looking for something like this,

Please replace the table name with your table name.

```
SELECT A.id, 
       A.cat, 
       A.date, 
       A.total_value, 
       A1.value 
FROM   (SELECT Max(id)    AS id, 
               cat, 
               Max(date)  AS Date, 
               Sum(value) AS Total_Value 
        FROM   tbl_sof 
        GROUP  BY cat) AS A 
       INNER JOIN tbl_sof A1 
               ON A.id = A1.id
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really help
haven't really thought of using nested which I should